# How do make my screen brightness not change when i charge my laptop

Tags: power-management, brightness

I do not want my laptop to change brightness when my laptop power is plugged in or unplugged. I set my brightness based on how bright my surroundings are. If I am in a dark room, I set my brightness very low and when I plug my laptop in the brightness gets set to maximum which is way to bright and will not go down even if i press the button.

My laptop is a Sony Vaio E Series, SVE15118FGW

Answer (score 1):

Open `System Settings -> Brightness and Lock` and uncheck the `Dim screen to save power` option.